# WCF Service in IIS bindings

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have inherited a WCF project which is hosted under IIS. Its part of a regular website i.e. there are human usable pages as well.

The site is configured in IIS with the following 2 bindings:

1: https://www.example.com/
2: http://www.example.com:8080/

If I visit http://www.example.com:8080/my-service.svc?wsdl I get a WSDL file returned as expected.

If I visit https://www.example.com/my-service.svc?wsdl I get told I need to visit http://www.example.com:8080/my-service.svc?wsdl to create a client.

There is no binding section under system.serviceModel in web.config.

What I want to know is, how does the service know it is associated with the second `IIS` binding and not the first.

system.ServiceModel follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="FormsAuthBehavior" type="My-WCF.FormsAuthBehaviorExtensionElement, EcobuttonWebService" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FormsAuthenticated">
          <!--To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!--To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <!--Pre-authenticates client with server to generate FormsAuthentication cookie. Cookie is submitted with each WCF request.-->
          <!--NB: set throwsSecurityExceptions="false" when updating service references in client apps.-->
          <FormsAuthBehavior throwsSecurityExceptions="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="My-Service" behaviorConfiguration="FormsAuthenticated" />
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Show Your web.config So that we can understand what you did wrong or missed something which is necessary ?

Comment: Could you show the web.config? 
And, in the service that doesn't exposing wsdl, the config has this line:
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> ?

Comment: OK, added the system.ServiceModel section.

Answer (score 0):

**Configure WCF Service for HTTP Transport Security**

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**Specify your service and service endpoint as shown in the following XML.**

```
<services>
      <service name="MySecureWCFService.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  contract="MySecureWCFService.IService1"/>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

**Enable httpsGetEnabled**

```
<serviceBehaviors>
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

**References:**

**[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx)**

**[Seven simple steps to enable HTTPS on WCF WsHttp bindings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi)**

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but that doesn't answer my question, being how does the service currently know what its binding is, when there is no binding in the web.config?

Comment: @DaleBurrell  for getting wsdl of `https://www.example.com/my-service.svc?wsdl` you have to configure bindings,service behaviors and endpoint (`mex`)

Comment: Thats what I thought! And thats why I am asking the question because its giving me a WSDL without having any bindings! Unless they can be compiled into the DLL somehow?

Comment: Is it possible for example to compile this configuration into the DLL?

Comment: @DaleBurrell i think you can  acheive this configuration by programaticaly (code) and then compile your code to get DLL

Comment: @DaleBurrell have a look on this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx